# How to find sub-arrays of a list in a more faster way in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
A = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
sub = [A[i:i+j] for i in range(0,len(A)) for j in range(1,len(A)-i+1)]
print(sub)
```

I would like to know if there is a way of finding sub-arrays faster than mine. The number of inputs in the list, 'A', can be from 1 to `10**5`, while the values that are inputted can be from 1 to `10**9`

EDIT:

A few samples of input data:

```
[1,0,3,0,4]

[1,10,10]

[2,6,13,4,3,2]
```

Note:This are just small samples, not really big ones

Comment: Can you post a small sample input and desired output?

Comment: @chrisz I only have small samples, but I am editing it for the samples

Comment: This is something like a superset problem. There are no computationally simpler algorithms. However, you can use `itertools.combination`.

Comment: I recommend fixing your answer a bit. Let A = [1, 2, 3, 4], and run your code and produce some output that you can paste here to let us understand what you're trying to do. If I'm not mistaken, this will solve your problem: `[A[i : j] for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(A) + 1), 2)]`

Comment: Do you need calculate all the values at once? If you could use just one value at a time, you could avoid some data copying overhead by reusing the same list.

Comment: An O(n) solution would also be helpful.

Comment: Operating in O(n) time is not possible, since there are O(n**2) results. But if you don't need to copy the data (which takes O(n) per result), you can use only O(n**2) time rather than O(n**3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to have all the results exist at once (e.g. you just need to print each one, then you can forget about it), you can speed your code up from `O(N**3)` to `O(N**2)`, simply by reusing the same lists, rather than slicing them anew on each iteration:

```
def print_subsequences(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        result = []
        for j in range(i,len(A)):
            result.append(A[j]
            print(result)
```

Example output:

```
>>> print_subsequences([1,2,3,4])
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3]
[3, 4]
[4]
```

You could also make the function a generator, yielding `result`s instead of printing them. But that is a little perilous, as the lists that would be yielded are not all independent of each other. If the consumer tried to save the `[2]` list from the example output, they'd find that it got changed after the next iteration to contain `[2,3]`, and further changed to `[2,3,4]` after the iteration after that. That could be a rather unpleasant surprise if they still needed the bare `[2]` list. You'd want to document the generator very clearly if you were going that route.